# \write or \index at the beginning of a table cell adds spurious vertical space

Tags: tables, boxes, write, whatsit

If a tabular column of type `p` (or a few others such as tabularx's `X`) starts with a `write` (for example because it starts with `\index`), this inserts some vertical space. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\writethis}{\write 1{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{4em}}
  \hline
  middle &o\writethis k\\ \hline
  start &\writethis foo\\ \hline
  end &foo\writethis \\ \hline
  alone &\writethis \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The “start” line has some extra vertical space above “foo”. If the `array` package is loaded, the “alone” box also has extra vertical space.

I understand part of what's going on, but not all. The `\write` command inserts a whatsis, which is a kind of box; when that box is “typeset” by the output routine, it causes the data to be written to the file, with no visual effect. No visual effect — except that somehow this causes a box with nonzero height to be typeset.

I have a solution for my use case: add `\leavevmode` before `\write`. I *think* this causes the whatsis to be a horizontal box instead of a vertical one and so I get a zero-width horizontal space instead of a nonzero-height vertical space, but I'm not sure. I'd like to understand what's going on. So I have several closely related questions:

1. Is my interpretation of the direction of the whatsis box correct?
2. Why does this box seemingly have nonzero height? What determines the height, or if the spurious vertical space isn't due to the whatsit box, what's causing it?
3. Why does the `array` package make a difference?
4. Is `leavevmode` a correct solution here (`\write` at the beginning of a LaTeX table cell)?

Comment: I haven’t got time to write an answer, but I can offer you a few hints. 1. the `p` specifier is implemented by means of a `\vtop`.  2. Read the rules for the height of a `\vtop` in the last paragraph of page 81 of _The TeXbook_, in particular rule (2).  3. Put `\showboxbreadth=10 \showboxdepth=1000 \showlists` right after `\end{tabular}` and you’ll see very clearly what’s happening, with and without the `array` package.  Hope this can be of help, otherwise wait for someone who’s got more time than I have… :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, expanding what @GustavoMezzetti (whom I thank) suggests, here is an explanation. I will quote and paraphrase the TeX Book during this post.

## Introduction

Let's start to understand what happens without `array`, ie at the basic TeX/LaTeX level. As Gustavo suggests, the `p` column is created using a `vtop`.

First we have to consider `vtop`'s sibling `vbox`. Please remark that `vbox` is a vertical box (containing other boxes) which has the same baseline as *the last box* inside of it. `vtop` is a similar structure but has the same baseline as *the first box* inside of it.

TeX has to do some kind of calculations to do for vertical material since it has *two* dimensions in that direction (height and depth), opposed to the single width when doing horizontal boxes.

### Vboxes

So, TeX, when constructing a `vbox` is basically concerned about establishing its depth, in order to make its baseline the same as the last (from top) box inside of it. Here are the steps that TeX undertakes in determining this:

1. If no boxes are inside the `vbox` then its depth `d` is `0pt`
2. If there is at least one box, but it's followed by kern or glue, "with possibly intervening penalties or other things" (sic.) the depth `d` is `0pt`
3. If there's at least one box and the *last* of them isn't followed by kern or glues, the depth `d` is set equal to the depth of that box

**Note:** there is a max depth value `boxmaxdepth` (its default value is  `16384pt`) which cannot be exceeded by the `vbox` depth. In case the depth calculated above is more than that quantity, the depth is set to `\boxmaxdepth` and the height is increased accordingly (practically this corresponds to moving the baseline down in order to obey the depth rules).

### Vtops

Now, when TeX is concerned with `vtops`, it's searching how to align the vertical box baseline with the first of the boxes inside of it, thus it will be concerned with the *height* of the box. It proceeds with the following steps:

1. Make a `vbox`, with the aforementioned rules. Let `d` and `h` be its depth and height
2. The final height `x` is calculated this way:

   1. If the first element of the `vbox` is not a box, then the height is `0pt`
   2. otherwise the height will be the height of the first box

Now the `vtop` gets build by shifting the `vbox` references so that the final height is `x` calculated in point 2, and the resulting box depth will be `h+d-x`

## Our case

The problem now is quite clear: when using the `\writethis` at the beginning of the `p` column, the `vtop` construction in step 2 sets the `height` of the `vbox` to be exactly `0pt`, so its reference point will be at the very top of it, thus messing up the alignment. Conceptually all of the content is in its depth, below the baseline.

### Array

The `array` package places a strut inside the cells of the table. This has an height of around `8.4pt`, with no depth set. The normal `hbox` containing the characters have an height of around `6.9pt` and depth of around `3.6pt`. So while in the previous (strut-less) example the `h`+`d` of the `vbox` (pre-rearrangement due to `vtop`) is ~`10.5pt`, when the strut comes into play, this is increased to ~`12pt` (the strut height plus the `hbox` depth). When rearranged, though, the total height of the `vtop` generated box is still `0pt` since its first element is not a box: this gives the extra space you have.

Comment: Beautifully explained!  But the part concerning the `array` package should be improved… ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti any suggestions about that? I had quite a hard time to gather all of the other informations. What do you feel missing from the `array` part?

Comment: `\showlists` will tell you (you want to deserve the reputation points you’ve earned, don’t you? ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I'm afraid `showlists` does not tell me anything more than what I just wrote, especially about the differences between "standard" and "array". I see nothing apart the strut

Comment: What I meant is that you negected to cover the peculiar case of the “alone” line, which is slightly different from the others, as `\showlists` will show you.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks, tomorrow I'll try and have a look

Comment: Well, the difference comes from the same “strut”, which, however, has a more dramatic effect in the case of the “alone” line.  BTW, if you haven’t already found it out (but I’m sure you have!), that “strut” comes from the (re)definition of `\@startpbox` made on lines 161–166 of `array.sty` [2016/10/06]: compare it with the original definition found on line 5397 of `latex.ltx` [2017/01/01 patch level 1]; and see also the two definitions of `\@endpbox`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks for the insight, I will try and edit it in tonight.